# Hide SPContenType in use

Tags: 2010, document-library, powershell, content-type

I'm trying to hide (or remove it from the new button drop) a SPContentType that is already in use via Powershell scripting.

Even if before:

```
$SPContentType.Hidden = $true
$SPContentType.Update()
```

I run:

```
$SPContentType.ReadOnly = $false
$SPContentType.Sealed = $false
$SPContentType.Update()
```

The exception error message "Content Type in use" is always throw.

Ideas? Is possible to hide an CTyte that's in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do a trick:

```
// Hide old content types.
$SPContentType.Group = "_Hidden";
$SPContentType.Update();
```

This will hide ContentType from Site settings but will leave it for all lists and libraries using it in order to save compatibility.

You can find best practices how to manage content types [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330223%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Hope it helps,

Andrew